# почему выводит none

Tags: python

четвертый день как стал изучать программирование и столкнулся с этим, в чем проблема должно записывать в .txt login а записывает None

```
введите сюда код

from tkinter import *

asd = Tk()

#asd.resizable(False, False)
asd.geometry('340x80+760+470')
asd.title("****")
asd.iconbitmap('C:/*****')
asd['bg'] = '#474747'



text = Label( text = 'Login', font = 'Comfortaa 14',
    fg = '#1cbced',
    bg = '#474747',
    padx= 6,
    pady=5).grid()

login = Entry (asd, font = 'consolas 15', 
    fg = '#ccc', # цвет текста
    bg = '#474747', # фоновый цвет кнопки
    relief = 'solid',width = 15,selectbackground = '#000', ).place(x = 65,y = 5 ) 

text_pas = Label(asd, text = 'Pass', font = 'Comfortaa 14',
    fg = '#1cbced',
    bg = '#474747',
    padx= 6,
    pady=5).grid()

def logacc():
    file = open('zxc.txt', "a" )
    file.write(str(login))




pas= Entry (asd, font = 'consolas 15',
    fg = '#ccc', # цвет текста
    bg = '#474747', # фоновый цвет кнопки
    relief = 'solid',width = 15).place(x = 65,y = 40)


butt_save = Button(text='SAVE',font = 'consolas 10', bg='#1cdfed',highlightcolo='#ed1cd8', width =12, command = logacc 
    ).place(x=245 ,y= 6,)

name = Entry (asd, font = 'consolas 15',
    fg = '#ccc', # цвет `введите сюда код`текста
    bg = '#474747', # фоновый цвет кнопки
    relief = 'solid',width = 8).place(x = 245,y = 40)

text_name = Label(asd, text = 'name', font = 'Comfortaa 8',
    fg = '#1cbced',
    bg = '#474747',height=1).place(x=295, y=60)



asd.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените на:

```
login = Entry(asd, font = 'consolas 15', fg='#ccc', bg='#474747', relief='solid', width=15, selectbackground='#000')
login.place(x=65, y=5)
```

И потом `login.get()`. Потому что сейчас у Вас `login` - значение функции `place()`, которая ничего не возвращает.